# Getting CURL post parameters right (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, post, linkedin-api

I'm trying to send a post request to the linkedin API using CURL. For some reason I get a response saying that I'm missing one variable.

```
array:2 [▼
  "error" => "missing_parameter"
  "error_description" => "A required parameter "client_id" is missing"
]
```

Here is my code and I can assure you that cliend_id is set.

```
    $code = $request->get("code");
    $state = $request->get("state");
    $redirect_uri = "http://example.com/linkedin/callback";
    $client_id = "1242435657";
    $client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXX";

    $url = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";

    $params = array(
        "grant_type" => 'authorization_code',
        "code" => $code,
        "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
        "client_id" => $client_id,
        "client_secret" => $client_key,
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // create an array from the data that is sent back from the API
    $result = json_decode($output, 1);
```

Is there anyway that I could debug this post request?

Comment: Try changing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));`

Comment: @BojanRadaković this does not change anything

Comment: I have a similar problem with Bearer token authentication. In my case I can see, that the POST data is not arriving to the server. Have you found a solution to your problem? Is there a way to debug post data request with curl? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736998/yii2-rest-authentication-bearer-post-data-missing

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma at the end of the last property and try again perhaps?

```
$params = array(
        "grant_type" => 'authorization_code',
        "code" => $code,
        "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
        "client_id" => $client_id,
        "client_secret" => $client_key, <=========
    );
```

Comment: this does not change anything.

Comment: Maybe you should just send them as a GET request. I tried this on the url: _https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken/?client_id=123&client_secret=123&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=uri&code=code_ And this is the error I received: _{"error":"invalid_client_id","error_description":"The passed in client_id is invalid \"123\""}_   . At least it doesn't say : _{"error":"missing_parameter","error_description":"A required parameter \"client_id\" is missing"}_ now.