# Yii2 Rest Authentication Bearer Post Data missing

Tags: rest, authentication, post, yii2, bearer-token

I'am working on a REST API. Therefore I prepared a function which sends the authentication data via curl to the REST Server. I've implemented two authentication options. The first is Basic Authentication, the second is authentication via token (Bearer).

Now, i'am in trobles, because at the REST Server, the POST Data is not received by the REST Server in case of authentication via token. The authentication itself is working, but the POST Data is going to be lost. In case of authentication via Basis Authentication, the POST Data will be received by the REST Server, no problem.

```
private function request($postdata){

    $url = $this->service_url_private;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $curl_post_data = $postdata;


    // check if token authentication is used
    if (array_key_exists('token', $postdata )){
        $token = $postdata['token'];
        $authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token;
        // prepare curl for Bearer Token Authorization
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization));
    } else {
        // otherwise use BASIC authentication
        if (array_key_exists('email', $postdata )){
            $username = $postdata['email'];
        }
        if (array_key_exists('password', $postdata )){
            $password = $postdata['password'];
        }
        // prepare curl for Basic Authentication
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // Detail information for debugging
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl); // Detail information for debugging
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl); // Detail information for debugging
    curl_close($curl);
    var_dump($info);
    return $curl_response;
}
```

In addition, $curl_post_data is showing all the data by the client while debugging, before the rest call will be executed with curl_exec($curl).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of hours I found the problem and the solution for this problem.

The problem is:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization));
```

Using 'Content-Type: application/json' results in loosing the POST data information.

Solution for this is:

change

```
'Content-Type: application/json'
```

to

```
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use yii2's HttpBasicAuth authenticator behaviour for bearer token auth.

```
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;

public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

[Authentication](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication#authentication)

For the solution you were suggesting, you should use json request parser.

```
'request' => [
  'parsers' => [
    'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
  ]
]
```

[JsonParser](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#enabling-json-input)

Answer (score 0):

Create new file with the following code and save it as mentioned in the namespace. Then use this file instead of \yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth.

```
<?php
namespace api\filters\auth;

use api\components\HttpResponseCode;
use yii\db\Exception;
use yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException;
class HttpBearerAuth extends \yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth {
    /**
     * @var string the HTTP authentication realm
     */
    public $realm = 'api';
    public $pattern = FALSE;
    public function authenticate($user, $request, $response) {
        $authHeader = $request->getHeaders()->get('Authorization');
        //  Following condition is added to support fastcgi issue.
        if ($authHeader === null) {
            $authHeader = $this->getBearerAuthFromSession();
            $this->pattern = '/^Bearer\s+(.*?)$/';
        }
        if ($authHeader !== null) {
            if ($this->pattern) {
                preg_match($this->pattern, $authHeader, $matches);
                $identity = $user->loginByAccessToken($matches[1], get_class($this));
            } else {
                $identity = $user->loginByAccessToken($authHeader, get_class($this));
            }
            if ($identity === null) {
                return $this->handleFailure($response);
            }
            return $identity;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public function challenge($response) {

        $response->getHeaders()->set('WWW-Authenticate', "Bearer realm=\"{$this->realm}\"");
    }
    public function handleFailure($response) {
        $e = new UnauthorizedHttpException('Your request was made with invalid credentials.');
        throw $e;
    }
    /**
     * In HttpBearerAuth, some development environments do not populate Authorization header in the request;
     * The issue is caused by CGI/FastCGI mode in Apache.
     * Following lines must be added in api/web/.htaccess:
     * # Authorization Headers
     * RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
     * RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
     * 
     * This function is used to access the following value in HttpBearerAuth to make it working :
     * $_SERVER[‘REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION’].
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getBearerAuthFromSession(): ?string {
        if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] != "") {
            return $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}
```