# Yii2 call PHP function in model dynamically from variable

Tags: function, variables, model, yii2, call

Is it possible to call a model function dynamically via variables?

```
$model = $request['model'];
$action = $request['action'];
```

I have some models and several functions inside. Now I would like to call a model function based on the variables $model and $action. In this case, I need to call the model functions dynamically, depending on a request.

Comment: you mean static function inside a class ??

Comment: The functions are public functions in classes mentioned above

Comment: the function are  static of or not ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static function

assuming you a class eg:

```
  \common\models\MyClass
```

with a

```
  public static function mStatyFunction()
  {

    ....
  }
```

you can use the class  name as  var

```
$myClass = '\common\models\MyClass';

$myClass::myStatFunction();
```

or if you need  also the the function name as  var you could

```
$myFunc = 'myStatFunction';

 $myClass::$myFunc();
```

for non static function you can simply   create a new object

```
public function myDinaFunction()
{
  ....
}

$myObject = new MyClass();
```

and call the function

```
$myObject->myDinaFunction();
```

or also

```
$var = 'myDinaFunction";

$myObject->$var();
```

Comment: Thank you scaisEdge for your quick support!

Comment: I dont know, how to contact you here, other than in this answer. Maybe you could also make a look to this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736998/yii2-rest-authentication-bearer-post-data-missing

Comment: @Perino  i have take a look but  i'm sorry at  the moment i have not experience in Bearer / REST  ..  so i think i'm not able to help you  ..

Comment: In your example for static function $myClass::myStatFunction(), how can I use myStatFunction() also as variable? In the non static function recommendation, I found out, that I have also to include the namespace to the class variable. If I choose the variant $myObject->$var, I end up with the problem: Undefined property: frontend\modules\rest\models\Member::$login ->where 'login' is the correct value of $var. That means the $var will be resolved to its value, but the system sets a '$' before?

Comment: for static function with funct in var answer  updated .. for test i'm using (php 5.6.31)  and work  ..  (obvious with proper namespace assigned )

Comment: I define $myObject = "frontend\\modules\\rest\\models\\" . $module; ...where module is the variable for classname. There are no Errors. (Single Backslash is not working, but I don't know why....). with $myObject->$var the Error comes up as mentioned above.

Comment: `'\frontend\modules\rest\models\'  .  $module ` (single quote, single slash and starting slash)  then ();

Comment: This is not working, I've tried it. With this variant, everything is outlined green behind, by the IDE (PhpStorm). $myClass = '\frontend\modules\rest\models\Member'; is working, $myClass = '\frontend\modules\rest\models\' . $module; is not working, not excepted by the IDE.

Comment: but this is IDE problem  ..non PHP  .. i'm  not using IDE  .. i'm using a simple  editor as SublimeText 3  .. and have tried  all th code provided .. and work ... so  if you need  this kind of source code manipulation  .. you should search how bypass  IDE constranis  .

Comment: It's also ok for me to work with the double BackSlashes in this case. Static variant is working with it. Non static variant shows the Error mentioned above. But I can go well with the Static variant! :-)