# PHP throws an exception in subroutine stops working

Tags: php, exception, yii, subroutine, throw

I have a custom class with function, which calls a function of the Yii2 core BasisAuthentication. In the core module is defined, if the credentials are not valid,

```
throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Your request was made with invalid credentials.');
```

With this, the whole request is ended. But I need to go further (because it is a REST request).

I've tried to prevent from that with

```
try {
     $identity = $basic_Auth->authenticate($user, $request, null );
} catch (Exception $e) {
     return null;
}
```

But this is not working. I don't want to adapt the core files of Yii. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean, `this is not working`? What are you doing with the returned value and what do you return when a login is successful?

Comment: Maybe you use php7 and there is ParseError or something? In that case you need to `catch (Throwable $e)`

Comment: @Nikita, yes it is PHP7 and your recommendation is working, thx! If you make an answer to the question, I could credit your fast response! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
     $identity = $basic_Auth->authenticate($user, $request, null );
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Nikita, I'am looking for somebody who is helping me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736998/yii2-rest-authentication-bearer-post-data-missing . Maybe you can help?